# Deconvolution vs Sub-pixel Convolution

Tags: neural-network, convolutional-neural-network, convolution

I recently read [Real-Time Single Image and Video Super-Resolution Using an Efficient Sub-Pixel Convolutional Neural Network](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.05158.pdf) by Wenzhe Shi et al. I cannot understand the difference between deconvolution (mentioned in Section 2.1) and the Efficient sub-pixel convolution layer (ESCL for short) (Section 2.2)

Section 2.2 defines the ESCL as performing convolution with a fractional stride. Isn't this what deconvolution is? Why is a distinction being made?

Thanks

Comment: Theory is good. But in practice I getting much clear result with sub-pixel conv rather than deconv, also sub-pixel learns faster.

Answer (score 6):

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.07009.pdf), theauthors have provided a deep explanation, basically its the exact same thing. sub-pixel uses o*r^2 conv kernels all at res H/r,W/r while the regular transpose conv uses o conv kernels all at res H,W the authors prove that one can rearrange the feature map (O*r^2,h,w) to a feature map (O,h*r,w*r) without losing information.